# Groupby: Count total sum of column for each year

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm fairly new to pandas, and I'm trying to figure out how to work with Groupby command. 
I've grouped my data by year, cik and boolean now I need to sum counts for true and false in each year separately.

I've tried `transform.(sum)['count']` but it adds all 3 years of my data. 
I would really appreciate any kind of help/ guidance.

Thanks!

```
df.groupby(['cik','isBase','FY'])['ext'].agg('count').head()

df['ext'] = np.where(df['isBase']== 'false', 1, 0)

df = df.groupby(['cik','isBase','FY',]['ext'].agg('count').reset_index(name='count')

df.head()

        cik     isBase  FY    count
    0   1750    false   2015    78
    1   1750    false   2016    73
    2   1750    false   2017    62
    3   1750    true    2015    328
    4   1750    true    2016    306
    5   1750    true    2017    305
```

I'm expecting an output to be something like this:

```
    cik    isBase   FY    count      totcount
0   1750    false   2015    78        406
1   1750    false   2016    73        376
2   1750    false   2017    62        367
3   1750    true    2015    328       406
4   1750    true    2016    306       376
5   1750    true    2017    305       367
```

As long as I can get a total count for each year's T+F

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df['totcount'] = df.groupby('FY')['count'].transform(sum)
```

Basically, `df.groupby('FY')` to group all rows with the same years, then and add the `df.groupby('FY')['count']` only look at the `count` column. Now `tranform(sum)` converts each year (group) to the corresponding sum.

Output:

```
+-----+------+--------+------+-------+----------+--+
| idx | cik  | isBase |  FY  | count | totcount |  |
+-----+------+--------+------+-------+----------+--+
|   0 | 1750 | False  | 2015 |    78 |      406 |  |
|   1 | 1750 | False  | 2016 |    73 |      379 |  |
|   2 | 1750 | False  | 2017 |    62 |      367 |  |
|   3 | 1750 | True   | 2015 |   328 |      406 |  |
|   4 | 1750 | True   | 2016 |   306 |      379 |  |
|   5 | 1750 | True   | 2017 |   305 |      367 |  |
+-----+------+--------+------+-------+----------+--+
```

Comment: Thank you, but my data is 4 million rows long (sorry for not clarifying that earlier), and it seems like it's summing all 'FY' counts... would you know if it's possible to have sum by two conditions 'cik' and 'FY' ?

Comment: 4 million rows are not too bad. Your solution is similar to mine, except the order of `transform`. Mine is better as it only transforms one column :p.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I have not been using my brackets correctly... This did the job

`df['totcount'] = df.groupby(['cik','FY']).transform(sum)['count']`